# Relationship between cumulative incidence and predicted probabilities in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, binary-data, lasso

We have a data where the cumulative incidence is around $10\%$ (i.e. $P(Y=1)=0.1$). But when we use a logistic regression (in fact, LASSO), find the predicted probabilities and plot a histogram of the predicted probabilities, it centers around $50\%-60\%$.

Is the distribution of the predicted probabilities not going to be centered around the cumulative incidence? Or a difference is expected because the predicted probabilities are $\hat{P}(Y=1|X)$ and are different from $P(Y=1)$? Am I confusing anything here?

Comment: Has all of this analysis you've described been performed on the same data set?

Comment: Yes, it is performed on the same data. Is it true that "if the predicted probabilities are around the overall incidence, that means the covariates are not good predictors, actually it means the covariates are of no use at all?" One clarification was like that. But I'm still confused if they will be so different. But if we predict higher risk for patients who actually had no events, how does that validate the model?

Comment: Exactly how have you computed the predicted probabilities?  Maybe there's an error in that process.

Comment: Actually in R, I used the command: predict(model, type="response") to get the predicted probabilities. So if I used no covariates, I'd get the predicted probability equal to the cumulative incidence. But should adding significant predictors make the distribution of the predicted probabilities go away from the cumulative incidence?

Comment: Normally it shouldn't.  Could you post the regression output.

Comment: Do you mean posting the graph of the predicted probabilities or the coefficients table?

Comment: The coefficients.